# Is @DgsComponent singleton

Tags: graphql-java, netflix-dgs

Is @DgsComponent(com.netflix.graphql.dgs.DgsComponent) singleton/thread safe?

- Created a data fetcher using @DgsComponenet
- & created a class level variable String temp
- Assessing if it is thread safe